# Comparing list comprehensions and explicit loops (3 array generators faster than 1 for loop)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, time, list-comprehension

I was doing my homework and accidentally found a strange inconsistency in the algorithm's speed.

Here are two code versions of the same function but with a difference. In the first version, I used `generators` three times to filter an array and in the second version, I used a `for` loop with three conditional statements to do the same filter work.

So, here is the code of the first version:

```py
def kth_order_statistic(array, k):
    pivot = (array[0] + array[len(array) - 1]) // 2
    l = [x for x in array if x < pivot]
    m = [x for x in array if x == pivot]
    r = [x for x in array if x > pivot]

    if k <= len(l):
        return kth_order_statistic(l, k)
    elif k > len(l) + len(m):
        return kth_order_statistic(r, k - len(l) - len(m))
    else:
        return m[0]
```

and here is the code of the second version:

```py
def kth_order_statistic2(array, k):
    pivot = (array[0] + array[len(array) - 1]) // 2
    l = []
    m = []
    r = []

    for x in array:
        if x < pivot:
            l.append(x)
        elif x > pivot:
            r.append(x)
        else:
            m.append(x)

    if k <= len(l):
        return kth_order_statistic2(l, k)
    elif k > len(l) + len(m):
        return kth_order_statistic2(r, k - len(l) - len(m))
    else:
        return m[0]
```

The IPython output for the first version is:

```
In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: A = range(100000)
   ...: shuffle(A)
   ...: k = randint(1, len(A)-1)
   ...: order_statisctic(A, k)
   ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop
```

And the IPython output for the second version is:

```
In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: A = range(100000)
   ...: shuffle(A)
   ...: k = randint(1, len(A)-1)
   ...: kth_order_statistic2(A, k)
   ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 169 ms per loop
```

So why is the first version faster than the second? I also made a third version which uses `filter()` function instead of an array `generator` and it was slower than the second version (it got 218 ms per loop)

Comment: List comprehensions are often faster than the equivalent for loops. Extending lists (your append functions) can also be more expensive than filling a list of known size.

Comment: increase your list sizes dramatically ... I think you will find that the gap is more or less constant ...  you are trading space for time, but they are *roughly* equivelent (there is a little bit of overhead on the generators/iterators vs the list)

Comment: @SohierDane This was my thinking. The list comprehension is explicit about what the operation is going to be that creates the list, therefore optimizations could be performed on it. Building the list element by element, Python can't make any assumptions about future calculations or memory usage.

Comment: The time is likely to vary significantly for different random orderings of `A` and different values of `k`. Make sure you're doing timings for the *same* `A` and `k` in both cases. I think you'll find that there's very little difference.

Comment: It is due to usage of `.append()` within the for loop. Added an answer with the insights regarding time difference.

Comment: You are calling `kth_order_statistic` in `kth_order_statistic2`

Comment: You *really* should use `numpy`.

Comment: @Flint, thank you for the correction, i edited post. In fact, the functions have different names and I corrected them in the form of a question, so it did not affect the results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's define the functions we will need to answer the question and timeit them:

```
In [18]: def iter():
    l = [x for x in range(100) if x > 10]
   ....:

In [19]: %timeit iter()
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.92 µs per loop

In [20]: def loop():
    l = []
    for x in range(100):
        if x > 10:
            l.append(x)
   ....:

In [21]: %timeit loop()
10000 loops, best of 3: 20 µs per loop

In [22]: def loop_fast():
    l = []
    for x in range(100):
        if x > 10:
            pass
   ....:

In [23]: %timeit loop_fast()
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.69 µs per loop
```

we can see that the for loops without the append command is as fast as the list comprehension. In fact, if we have a look at the bytecode we can see that in the case of the list comprehension python is able to use a built-in bytecode command called LIST_APPEND instead of:

- Load the list: 40 LOAD_FAST
- Load the attribute: 43 LOAD_ATTRIBUTE
- Call the loaded function: 49 CALL_FUNCTION
- Unload the list(?): 52 POP_TOP

As you can see from the output below the previous bytecode are missing with list comprehension and with the "loop_fast" function. Comparing the timeit of the three function is clear that those are responsible for the different timing of the three methods.

```
In [27]: dis.dis(iter)
  2          0 BUILD_LIST             0
             3 LOAD_GLOBAL            0 (range)
             6 LOAD_CONST             1 (1)
             9 LOAD_CONST             2 (100)
            12 CALL_FUNCTION          2
            15 GET_ITER
       >>   16 FOR_ITER              24 (to 43)
            19 STORE_FAST             0 (x)
            22 LOAD_FAST              0 (x)
            25 LOAD_CONST             2 (100)
            28 COMPARE_OP             4 (>)
            31 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE     16
            34 LOAD_FAST              0 (x)
            37 LIST_APPEND            2
            40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         16
       >>   43 STORE_FAST             1 (l)
            46 LOAD_CONST             0 (None)
            49 RETURN_VALUE

In [28]: dis.dis(loop)
  2          0 BUILD_LIST             0
             3 STORE_FAST             0 (1)

  3          6 SETUP_LOOP            51 (to 60)
             9 LOAD_GLOBAL            0 (range)
            12 LOAD_CONST             1 (1)
            15 LOAD_CONST             2 (100)
            18 CALL_FUNCTION          2
            21 GET_ITER
       >>   22 FOR_ITER              34 (to 59)
            25 STORE_FAST             1 (x)

  4         28 LOAD_FAST              1 (x)
            31 LOAD_CONST             3 (10)
            34 COMPARE_OP             4 (>)
            37 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE     22

  5         40 LOAD_FAST              0 (l)
            43 LOAD_ATTR              1 (append)
            46 LOAD_FAST              1 (x)
            49 CALL_FUNCTION          1
            52 POP_TOP
            53 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         22
            56 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         22
       >>   59 POP_BLOCK
       >>   60 LOAD_CONST             0 (None)
            63 RETURN_VALUE

In [29]: dis.dis(loop_fast)
  2          0 BUILD_LIST             0
             3 STORE_FAST             0 (1)

  3          6 SETUP_LOOP            38 (to 47)
             9 LOAD_GLOBAL            0 (range)
            12 LOAD_CONST             1 (1)
            15 LOAD_CONST             2 (100)
            18 CALL_FUNCTION          2
            21 GET_ITER
       >>   22 FOR_ITER              21 (to 46)
            25 STORE_FAST             1 (x)

  4         28 LOAD_FAST              1 (x)
            31 LOAD_CONST             3 (10)
            34 COMPARE_OP             4 (>)
            37 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE     22

  5         40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         22
            43 JUMP_ABSOLUTE         22
       >>   46 POP_BLOCK
       >>   47 LOAD_CONST             0 (None)
            50 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 10):

Using simple `for` is faster than `list comprehesion`. It is almost 2 times faster. Check below results:

Using `list comprehension`: *58 usec*

```
moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m timeit "[i for i in range(1000)]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 58 usec per loop
```

Using `for` loop: *37.1 usec*

```
moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m timeit "for i in range(1000): i"
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.1 usec per loop
```

But in your case, `for` loop is taking more time than `list comprehension` not because your `for` loop is slow, but because of the `.append()` method that you are using within the code.

With `append()` in `for` loop: *114 usec*

```
moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m timeit "my_list = []" "for i in range(1000): my_list.append(i)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 usec per loop
```

Which clearly shows that it is the `.append()` method which is taking twice the time taken by `for` loop.

However, on storing the `list.append()` in different variable: *69.3 usec*

```
moin@moin-pc:~$ python -m timeit "my_list = []; append = my_list.append" "for i in range(1000): append(i)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.3 usec per loop
```

There is a huge improvement in the performance as compared to the last case in above comparisons, and result is quite comparable to that of `list comprehension`. That means, instead of calling `my_list.append()` each time, the performance can be improved by storing the reference of function in another variable i.e `append_func = my_list.append` and making a call using that variable `append_func(i)`.

Which also proves, **it is faster to call class's function stored in the variable as compared to directly making the function call using object of the class**.

*Thank You [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann) for bringing the last case in notice.*

Comment: One is three seperate loops over a list of size n, and there other is a single loop. A better argument could be made by showing how expensive `append` is.

Comment: @sdsmith: Yes. I should have provided the insights. Updated the answer

Comment: What do you get for `python -m timeit "my_list = []; append = my_list.append" "for i in range(1000): append(i)"`?

Comment: Updated the answer. Thank you for bringing it on plate.

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri. Regarding @sdsmith and @Stefan Pochmann  comments, it appears you need to update the first paragraph of your answer, *"Using simple for is faster than list comprehension"*. Your first  comparison is wrong. Let's simply compare comparable things : like `python -m timeit "my_list = []; append = my_list.append" "for i in range(1000): append(i)" ` **vs**  `python -m timeit "a=[i for i in range(1000)]; a"`

Answer (score 3):

Let's dissipate that doubt :
The **second version** is slightly faster : **list comprehension are faster**, yet two arrays looping and as much conditionals are discarded in one iteration.

```
def kth_order_statistic1(array,k):
    pivot = (array[0] + array[len(array) - 1]) // 2
    l = [x for x in array if x < pivot]
    m = [x for x in array if x == pivot]
    r = [x for x in array if x > pivot]

    if k <= len(l):
        return kth_order_statistic1(l, k)
    elif k > len(l) + len(m):
        return kth_order_statistic1(r, k - len(l) - len(m))
    else:
        return m[0]


def kth_order_statistic2(array,k):
    pivot = (array[0] + array[len(array) - 1]) // 2
    l = []
    m = []
    r = []
    for x in array:
        if x < pivot:
            l.append(x)
        elif x > pivot:
            r.append(x)
        else:
            m.append(x)

    if k <= len(l):
        return kth_order_statistic2(l, k)
    elif k > len(l) + len(m):
        return kth_order_statistic2(r, k - len(l) - len(m))
    else:
        return m[0]

def kth_order_statistic3(array,k):
    pivot = (array[0] + array[len(array) - 1]) // 2
    l = []
    m = []
    r = []

    for x in array: 
       if x < pivot: l.append(x)
    for x in array: 
       if x== pivot: m.append(x)
    for x in array: 
       if x > pivot: r.append(x)

    if k <= len(l):
        return kth_order_statistic3(l, k)
    elif k > len(l) + len(m):
        return kth_order_statistic3(r, k - len(l) - len(m))
    else:
        return m[0]

import time
import random
if __name__ == '__main__':

    A = range(100000)
    random.shuffle(A)
    k = random.randint(1, len(A)-1)

    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1000) :
        kth_order_statistic1(A,k)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1000) :
        kth_order_statistic2(A,k)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1000) :
        kth_order_statistic3(A,k)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

```
python :
--- 25.8894710541 seconds ---
--- 24.073086977 seconds ---
--- 32.9823839664 seconds ---

ipython
--- 25.7450709343 seconds ---
--- 22.7140650749 seconds ---
--- 35.2958850861 seconds ---
```

The timing may vary according to the random draw, but the differences between the three are pretty much the same.

Comment: You did not consider that the function modifies the array, in this context, the following function call to the same array will reduce the work function. 
Because of this, I measured the time with the shuffle function. But this will not affect on your results. Thanks for answer

Comment: What ? No, the array is not written back, it's used only as input. Besides, if you gives different arrays to the functions, you'll get biased results since the workload depends also on the random distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithmic structure differs and the conditional structure is to be incriminated. the test to append into r and m can be discarded by the previous test. A more strict comparison regarding a for loop with `append`, and list comprehension would be against the non-optimal following

```
for x in array:
        if x < pivot:
            l.append(x)
for x in array:
        if x== pivot:
            m.append(x)
for x in array:
        if x > pivot:
            r.append(x)
```