# How do I find a value relative to where a list occurs within my list in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, markov-chains

I have a list of numbers:

```
Data = [0,2,0,1,2,1,0,2,0,2,0,1,2,0,2,1,1,...]
```

And I have a list of tuples of two, which is all possible combinations of the individual numbers above:

```
Combinations = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

I want to try to find where each item in Combinations appears in Data and add the value after each occurrence to another list.

For example, for (0,2) I want to make a list [0,0,0,1] because those are the the values that fall immediately after (0,2) occurs in Data.

So far, I have:

```
any(Data[i:i+len(CurrentTuple)] == CurrentTuple for i in xrange(len(Data)-len(CurrentTuple)+1))
```

Where `CurrentTuple` is `Combinations.pop()`. 
The problem is that this only gives me a Boolean of whether the `CurrentTuple` occurs in Data. What I really need is the value after each occurrence in Data.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how this can be solved? Thanks!

Comment: If you need something faster (I imagine that if you are working with markov-chain this is the case) check also my answer below... Avoiding `append` makes list generation much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict to group the data to see where/if any comb lands in the original list zipping up pairs:

```
it1, it2 = iter(Data), iter(Data)
next(it2)

Combinations = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

d = {c: [] for c in Combinations}
ind = 2
for i, j in zip(it1, it2):
    if (i, j) in d and ind < len(Data):
        d[(i, j)].append(Data[ind])
    ind += 1
print(d)
```

Which would give you:

```
{(0, 1): [2, 2], (1, 2): [1, 0], (0, 0): [], (2, 1): [0, 1], (1, 1): [2], (2, 0): [1, 2, 1, 2], (2, 2): [], (1, 0): [2], (0, 2): [0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

You could also  do it in reverse:

```
from collections import defaultdict

it1, it2 = iter(Data), iter(Data)
next(it2)
next_ele_dict = defaultdict(list)
data_iter = iter(Data[2:])
for ind, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(it1, it2)):
    if ind < len(Data) -2:
      next_ele_dict[(i, j)].append(next(data_iter))

def next_ele():
    for comb in set(Combinations):
        if comb in next_ele_dict:
           yield comb, next_ele_dict[comb]

print(list(next_ele()))
```

Which would give you:

```
 [((0, 1), [2, 2]), ((1, 2), [1, 0]), ((2, 1), [0, 1]), ((1, 1), [2]), ((2, 0), [1, 2, 1, 2]), ((1, 0), [2]), ((0, 2), [0, 0, 0, 1])]
```

Any approach is better than a pass over the Data list for every element in Combinations.

To work for arbitrary length tuples we just need to create the tuples based on the length:

```
from collections import defaultdict

n = 2

next_ele_dict = defaultdict(list)

def chunks(iterable, n):
    for i in range(len(iterable)-n):
        yield tuple(iterable[i:i+n])

data_iter = iter(Data[n:])
for tup in chunks(Data, n):
      next_ele_dict[tup].append(next(data_iter))

def next_ele():
    for comb in set(Combinations):
        if comb in next_ele_dict:
            yield comb, next_ele_dict[comb]


print(list(next_ele()))
```

You can apply it to whatever implementation you prefer, the logic will be the same as far as making the tuples goes.

Comment: This one works only if you want to compare couples of numbers

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia *If you are only considering non-overlapping pairs, (0,2)*, it can easily be adapted for the other case but since the OP reckons only three cases of `(0, 2)` happens then they must not be ]

Comment: Yes, but what he wrote works also if you decide to compare "triples" of numbers

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia, where do you see that in the question? **I have a list of tuples of two**

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia, the OP would probably want to first verify their  expected output before we verify what is not there ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you! This is very helpful, however I did forget to mention in the question that I need this to work for tuples of any length... Is there a way to adapt:

it1, it2 = iter(Data), iter(Data)
next(it2)

Combinations = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

d = {c: [] for c in Combinations}
ind = 2
for i, j in zip(it1, it2):
    if (i, j) in d and ind < len(Data):
        d[(i, j)].append(Data[ind])
    ind += 1
print(d)

to work for tuples of all lengths? Thanks again!

Comment: @SantiTellez,  are the tuples always going to be the same length?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, the tuples will always be the same length. This code is to build a Markov Chain of nth order where the tuples are of n length, so they will always be the same. Thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: No worries,  we can do it, I am just finishing off some work and then I will add it. Basically all we need to do is consider the the length of the tuples.

Comment: @SantiTellez, the last snippet should work for any length

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you so much! It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([all(x) for x in (Data[i:i+len(CurrentTuple)] == CurrentTuple for i in xrange
(len(Data)-len(CurrentTuple)+1))])
```

What you did return a generator that produce the following list:

```
[array([False,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([ True, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True], dtype=bool),
 ...
 array([False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False,  True], dtype=bool)]
```

One of the array that you have in this list match the `CurrentTuple` only if both the `bool` in the array are `True`. The `all` return `True` only if all the elements of the list are `True` so the list generated by the `[all(x) for x in ...]` will contains `True` only if the twin of numbers match the `CurrentTuple`. A `True` is conted as `1` when you use `sum`. I hope it is clear.

If you want to compare only non-overlapping pairs:

```
[2,2,
 0,2,
 ...]
```

and keep the algorithm as general as possible, you can use the following:

```
sum([all(x) for x in (Data[i:i+len(CurrentTuple)] == CurrentTuple for i in xrange
(0,len(Data)-len(CurrentTuple)+1,len(CurrentTuple)))])
```

Despite much more cryptic, this code is much faster than any alternative that using `append` (look [[Comparing list comprehensions and explicit loops (3 array generators faster than 1 for loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518899/3-array-generators-faster-than-1-for-loop/39519661#39519661]) to understand why).