# Slowness on iterating over namedtuple and dicts for defined pairs

Tags: python, collections, defaultdict, namedtuple

This code runs quickly on the sample data, but when iterating over a large file, it seems to run slowly, perhaps because of the nested for loops. Is there any other reason why iterating over items in a defaultdict is slow?

```
import itertools

sample_genes1={"0002":["GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3", "GENE4"],
               "0003":["GENE1", "GENE2", "GENE3", "GENE6"],
               "0202":["GENE4", "GENE2", "GENE1", "GENE7"]}

def get_common_gene_pairs(genelist):
    genedict={}
    for k,v in sample_genes1.items():
        listofpairs=[]
        for i in itertools.combinations(v,2):
            listofpairs.append(i)
            genedict[k]=listofpairs
    return genedict

from collections import namedtuple,defaultdict
def get_gene_pair_pids(genelist):
    i=defaultdict(list)
    d=get_common_gene_pairs(sample_genes1)
    Pub_genes=namedtuple("pair", ["gene1", "gene2"])
    for p_id,genepairs in d.iteritems():
        for p in genepairs:
            thispair=Pub_genes(p[0], p[1])
            if thispair in i.keys():
                i[thispair].append(p_id)
            else:
                i[thispair]=[p_id,]
    return i

if __name__=="__main__":
    get_gene_pair_pids(sample_genes1)
```

Comment: One of the first things you should do to solve problems like this is profile your code. See [_How can you profile a Python script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) to find out how easy it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big problem: this line:

```
if thispair in i.keys():
```

doesn't take advantage of dictionary search, it's linear search. Drop the `keys()` call, let the dictionary do its fast lookup:

```
if thispair in i:
```

BUT since `i` is a default dict which creates a `list` when key doesn't exist, just replace:

```
if thispair in i.keys():
    i[thispair].append(p_id)  # i is defaultdict: even if thispair isn't in the dict, it will create a list and append p_id.
else:
    i[thispair]=[p_id,]
```

by this simple statement:

```
i[thispair].append(p_id)
```

(it's even faster because there's only one hashing of `p_id`)

to sum it up:

- don't do `thispair in i.keys()`: it's slow, in python 2, or 3, `defaultdict` or not
- you have defined a `defaultdict`, but your code just assumed a `dict`, which works but slower.

Note: without `defaultdict` you could have just removed the `.keys()` or done this with a simple `dict`:

```
i.setdefault(thispair,list)
i[thispair].append(p_id)
```

(here the default item depends on the key)

Aside:

```
def get_common_gene_pairs(genelist):
    genedict={}
    for k,v in sample_genes1.items():  # should be genelist, not the global variable, you're not using the genelist parameter at all
```

And you're not using the *values* of sample_genes1 at all in your code.

Comment: Perfectly explained. It would be great if you could mention the use of `setdefault` in order to skip `if` lookups

Comment: Never mind. I think it is useless since OP know about `defaultdict` *(which I missed)*. Just mentioning the correct use of `defaultdict` suffices here

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, really appreciate the time and care :D

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [*Jean's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41578905/2063361), your `get_common_gene_pairs` function could be optimized by using *dict comprehension* as:

```
def get_common_gene_pairs(genelist):
    return {k : list(itertools.combinations(v,2)) for k,v in genelist.items()}
```

*list.append()* is much more time consuming compared to it's *list comprhension* counter part. Also, you don't have to iterate over `itertools.combinations(v,2)` in order to convert it to list. Type-casting it to `list` does that.

Here is the comparison I made between *list comprehension* and `list.append()` in answer to [Comparing list comprehensions and explicit loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518899/comparing-list-comprehensions-and-explicit-loops-3-array-generators-faster-than/39518977#39518977), in case you are interested in taking a look.

Comment: great! I love learning more about the theoretical basis of why I should be doing things a certain way, thank you very much.  I am going to work on adding list comprehensions to my repertoire.