# Complex List Comprehension slower than straight loop

Tags: python

I saw an interesting solution for a programming exercise on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/fizz-buzz/)  It's not even about the problem/solution itself, so you can read it up on the link provided if you wish. However a high voted solution is this one liner:

## Snippet 1

```
def fizzBuzz2(n):
    return  ["Fizz" * (not i%3) + "Buzz" * (not i%5) or str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

## Snippet 2

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    out = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            out.append("FizzBuzz")
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            out.append("Fizz")
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            out.append("Buzz")
        else:
            out.append(str(i))
            
    return out
```

However, I've expected that the list comprehension is going to beat the common loop, but when I've timed it and it wasn't the case. Even doing a dis, Snippet 2 has more instructions.

What is making **Snippet 1** slow?

Comment: snippet 2 is slower in my test. And btw there's a stray `self` in it.

Comment: String concatenation vs. literal strings, but Snippet 2 also does twice as many `%` operations as necessary.

Comment: I cannot check it myself atm but is it possible that the list comprehension checks all statements whereas the if elif structure checks only until one condition holds true?

Comment: Thanks for the stray self, did u use a high number n? like 1.000.000 ?

Comment: I did some analysis in past for [Comparing list comprehensions and explicit loops (3 array generators faster than 1 for loop)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39518977/2063361) . You may find it useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your snippet

```
def fizzBuzz2(n):
    return  ["Fizz" * (not i%3) + "Buzz" * (not i%5) or str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

performs a lot of string concatenations (even with empty strings). I traded that with an extra modulo operation which saves the concatenation and it's already faster.

```
def fizzBuzz3(n):
    return  ["FizzBuzz" if not i%15 else "Fizz" if not i%3 else "Buzz" if not i%5 else str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

and BTW on my machine, both comprehensions are faster than the "classical" approach so I get different results than you stated:

```
your comp: 4.927702903747559
my listcomp: 4.343341112136841
classical: 6.015967845916748
```

So my optimized listcomp wins (and seems to win too on your machine), even if I'm not satisfied with the extra modulo operations induced by the flow control of the listcomp)

My test protocol is performing 10000 times the operation with `n=1000`:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    fizzBuzz2(1000)
print("your comp:",time.time()-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    fizzBuzz3(1000)
print("my listcomp:",time.time()-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    fizzBuzz(1000)
print("classical:",time.time()-start_time)
```

note that even with pre-computing the modulos in the "classical" approach, it drops to `5.375272035598755` seconds (which is good) but still worse than listcomps because of all the instructions (you also kill the listcomp speed by calling a method to save modulo computations). I guess that python is not the proper language to obtain the fastest speed in that case.

Comment: That's weird, i mean it's weird that when you run classical it's slower, my results: classical: 3.7922539711, list comp: 3.95321893692, your list comp; 2.85592794418

Comment: so my optimized listcomp is the fastest of the 3? that's still good news :)

Comment: Haha yes, just as a note, your machine is slow dude, here is me running your test protocoll:
('your comp:', 3.3554258346557617)
('my listcomp:', 2.2999539375305176)
('classical:', 3.1437509059906006)

Comment: yeah. coding is too easy on a fast machine :) What makes the test weird is probably that your machine is not very well balanced: I mean you may have very fast RAM or very fast CPU, whereas us mere mortals have "standard" ratios for each critical resource.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people already answered your question, but I want to add that there are still faster solutions. To me it seems wrong to test the numbers in hindsight, although you already know at which places "Fizz", "Buzz" and "FizzBuzz" will occur. Try this instead:

```
def fizz_buzz(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1, 15):
        result += [str(i), str(i + 1), 'Fizz',
                   str(i + 3), 'Buzz', 'Fizz',
                   str(i + 6), str(i + 7), 'Fizz', 'Buzz',
                   str(i + 10), 'Fizz', str(i + 12), str(i + 13),
                   'FizzBuzz']
    return result[:n - len(result)]

start_time = time()
for i in range(10000):
    fizz_buzz(1000)
print("fizz_buzz:", time() - start_time)
```

Compared to the previous answers:

```
your comp: 3.3942723274230957
my listcomp: 2.586350202560425
classical: 3.879168748855591
fizz_buzz: 1.6374053955078125
```

Comment: BTW you can be even faster using your solution combined with listcomp & `itertools.chain.from_iterable`: `result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([str(i), str(i + 1), 'Fizz',
                   str(i + 3), 'Buzz', 'Fizz',
                   str(i + 6), str(i + 7), 'Fizz', 'Buzz',
                   str(i + 10), 'Fizz', str(i + 12), str(i + 13),
                   'FizzBuzz'] for i in range(1, n + 1, 15)))
    return result[:n - len(result)]`

Comment: Isn’t `[:n - len(result)]` just `[:n]`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre are you sure about that? I've replaced the result line with your's and it's taking orders of magnitude longer to finish.

Comment: yes, I've benched that and it's even faster on my machine (oh, I hope you did remove the loop!!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because in the comprehension all the instructions are being evaluated in each loop.

While in `Snippet 2` atmost 1 `if` branch is evaluated. Thus, reducing the computation, and making it a faster alternative.

Answer (score 1):

While we’re exploring implementations, here’s a fun slice one that’s faster than the single list comprehension, but not as fast as @seenorth’s solution:

```
from math import ceil


def fizz_buzz(n):
    result = list(range(n))
    result[::3] = ["Fizz"] * ceil(n / 3)
    result[::5] = ["Buzz"] * ceil(n / 5)
    result[::15] = ["FizzBuzz"] * ceil(n / 15)

    return list(map(str, result))
```